# Something is stealing focus from the active window

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

Some kind of program is stealing focus from the active window, it's quite strange. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

So for example I open Notepad++ and start typing. After some time (few minutes, sometimes even less), the window loses focus and the program does not receive input anymore. Same with other programs, it's quite annoying.

I already checked for malicious programs. The only change I made to the computer before the problem started occurring is the installation of a new TP-Link USB wireless adapter.

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the only change I made in a reasonable time was adding the wireless adapter, I thought the problem should be related to that. I investigated by reverting things I have done step-by-step, first removing the wireless adapter, then closing software that came with it (using the Task Manager).

Turned out it was the **TP-Link Wireless Utility**.

Got rid of it and it is fine now. It is not necessary for the wireless adapter to function.

[@Andrew Thompson reports](https://superuser.com/questions/525826/something-is-stealing-focus-from-the-active-window/525827#comment1018879_525827) that *one and a half year* after I posted this question this problem still has not been fixed by TP-Link.

Comment: Is there any method you used to track this down? Or just trial and error? Otherwise this question would simply be too localized to the one situation you had, and thus not really helpful for other visitors with the same issue.

Comment: @slhck Basically started closing running programs from Task Manager. Since then I found out that this wireless utility is causing a lot of problems for other people too, so I thought it would be useful to share this. But no matter, this is my first closed question on SE, it seems to be fun :).

Comment: DYM the 'TP-LINK Wireless *Configuration* Utility'?  I seem to be having the same problem!

Comment: *"Since then I found out that this wireless utility is causing a lot of problems for other people too"*  (raises hand)  Just solved the problem on my machine over a year and a half after your answer, thanks to your heads-up.  And this was for a *new card* (the guy that supplied it was grumbling that he'd quoted it to cost $X for the motherboard connector he was expecting, but it used the 'new style connector' and cost $X+10), some *year and a half* after your report.  I disagree that it is 'too localized', though it seems a very poor software support effort on the part of TP-Link. :-/

Comment: **Raised a support ticket: crux**  Ticket ID #58082
Full Name Andrew Thompson
Email ???@gmail.com

Subject: TP-LINK Wireless Configuration Utility repeatedly steals input focus on Windows 7  
 
Hi folks,

The software mentioned in the subject of this Support Ticket has been repeatedly and (seemingly) randomly been stealing keyboard input focus on Windows 7 based machines. This problem seems to have lasted at least the last 18 months. 

Could you fix it?


See also http://superuser.com/a/525827/99314 where this problem has been discussed.

Comment: @slhck Seems like this was useful for future visitors, so I decided to edit the question and the answer to make it "less localized" and contain more information, hoping for a reopen to possibly help even more people.

Comment: Sure thing, seems useful.