# Windows 7 - Constantly switching focus to nothing

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

I have this strange problem where Windows (7) is just changing focus all the time.

I tried using the Focus.exe
(http://www.happydroid.com/focus)

it shows every time this happens the line:

> No foreground application

and then comes back to the last focused window.

In other words - it's not a program that's stealing the focus (!)

But maybe Windows itself...

Tried Process Monitor, Process Explorer and Windows Event Viewer - Nothing unusual there.

It's impossible to use editing software and games like that...

I'll add more information when I'll have it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something is stealing focus from the active window](http://superuser.com/questions/525826/something-is-stealing-focus-from-the-active-window)

Comment: what do You mean by focus (focus.exe) exactly? I am sorry to ask but it is not clear for me.

Comment: Sound strange... so first thing to try, boot into Safe Mode to check if there is focus stealing problem, if no, use `msconfig` to disable all startup item then check again

Comment: Think back to the time before this problem appeared (not long ago, hopefully). What software have you installed since then?

Comment: @DavidPostill - I checked and it is not a program but the system itself switching focus

Comment: @Bilo Tried, nothing new - same problem

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev nothing new on my PC, I reinstalled the MoBo in a new case and reinstalled the Nvidia driver (uninstalled using DDU)

Comment: @Divin3 I posted a link - check it to see what it is

Comment: Please explain what is same problem? Are you still having focus stealing problem even in safe mode?

Comment: Problem is solved, see my answer

Comment: Something similar is going on here too. I am checking now with focus.exe. Sometimes Firefox loses focus when I am typing, it's annoying. Another problem that in fps games I use alt + shift sometimes to run and check the stats meanwhile and the same combination changes language in Windows. By my old install that was not a problem it kept the default language. By this install it always changes the keyboard language. So I guess the first person shooter (full screen app) loses focus too somehow. I already used DDU, it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suddenly stopped after:

- Uninstalling some old games
- Re-Installing Graphics Drivers (using DDU)
- Re-Installing Codec Packs (K-Lite)

Problem is solved

Thanks.